# Algorithm and Data Structure - Queue

Tags: queue

The 2 queueing strategies are as follows:
1. A single queue. Each server will take the next customer as soon as the server becomes available.
2. A queue for each server. Customers will choose the server with the shortest queue on arrival and not allowed to jump queue thereafter.

Can someone explain the 2nd queue? It means the same thing as the first queue just that the customer will choose the shortest one(which means will faster process the customer) to queue. Where can I get more information of this queue or if there is any sample code?

Comment: The first model is like shopping at Fry's.  Everyone waits in a single line.  The next available cashier asks the customer at the front of the line to come to their cash register to checkout.

Comment: The second model (queue for each server) is like checking out at a grocery store. You pick the line based on the shortest number of customers or perceived wait based on what you observe in the grocery cart. The person in front of you might have 1 item or 100 items to buy.  Your wait time is variable.

Comment: @selbie I think your two examples would make a good answer.

Comment: Your assumption that the shortest queue is also the fastest only holds if every customer is processed in exactly the same amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Image representing the two queuing strategies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcGav.png)

It has been found out that the single queue - multiple servers approach is more efficient than the multiple queues approach. In this approach, the waiting time is almost equally distributed among all the customers, even though the processing time for each customer is different.

Here is a link to a detailed analysis and mathematical proof of the same.

[Comparison Between Single and Multiple Queues](https://goldenratiphi.wordpress.com/2013/05/06/comparison-between-single-and-multiple-queues/)